# How do I paint textures without adding a material?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, materials, node-editor

[image]I am using Cycles Render and an Image Texture Node so that I can paint my texture and remove seams.  However, in order to do this I have to add a material and that causes my object to be shiny, which is not the look I'm going for.  How do I keep the new texture (I have saved the painted texture image as a new file on my desktop) but lose the material?  I've tried removing the material from the properties bar and then opening the new texture image in the texture section of the properties bar, but that just turns my object white.

Comment: You can't just have a texture floating around directly applied to an object, that texture has to belong to a material. If the material is too shiny why not adjust it to match what you expect?

Comment: What material do you create that object becomes "too shiny"? Default Diffuse shader barely gives that, could you show screenshots of your setup?

Comment: I think it's the default diffuse material, but I liked how it looked before-- completely flat.

Comment: Never assess a cycles material using textured view. Use Rendered view, what you describe as shiny is just not part of the material at all.